# Writing test case in XCTest to testing code coverage in iOS

Tags: ios, ios8, code-coverage, xctest

I have integrate CoverStory software which allows me to view my code coverage. But I was unable to write test cases which can give me non 0 code coverage. Every time I am getting 0% code coverage.